# Proving $f_n(x)=\frac{1+\cos^2(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

We wish to prove that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{1+\cos^2(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Scratch work:
$|f_n(x)|=|\frac{1+\cos^2(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|\le|\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}|$

If we have $$|\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}| <\varepsilon \implies n>\frac{4}{\varepsilon^2} $$

Proof:
$\varepsilon>0$ is given, we choose $N = \lceil \frac{4}{\varepsilon^2} \rceil$ $n>N$ is given.

We know $n>N\ge \frac{4}{\varepsilon^2}$
$|f_n(x)|=|\frac{1+\cos^2(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}|\le|\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}|$
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{2}{2/\varepsilon}=\varepsilon$$

Hence the function converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Seems ok to me, good job!

Comment: I would stop at the first line: $\sup_\Bbb R |f|\le \frac{2}{\sqrt n}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt n}\to0$ trivially. Finding $N$ for a given $\varepsilon$ looks overkill to me. But depending on what you are supposed to do (and how far you are supposed to show you know how to use the definition), it may be worth writing the whole thing.